# Flask not seeing environment variables set in Passenger (Dreamhost hosting)

Tags: python, flask, environment-variables, passenger, dreamhost

I am deploying my first Flask project. I have a contact form on the website that works if I set app.config to the literal string, like so:

```
app.config["MAIL_USERNAME"] = "xxxxxx@xxxxxxxxx.com"
app.config["MAIL_PASSWORD"] = "xxxxxxxxxxx"
```

so I know that the actual python code is working correctly. my issue comes when I try to set them as environment variables, like so:

```
import os
app.config["MAIL_USERNAME"] = os.environ.get('MAILUSER')
app.config["MAIL_PASSWORD"] = os.environ.get('MAILPASS')
```

Moving on to the actual web server. when I ssh into the webserver, the environment variables are set correctly (I have triple checked them). in a new terminal I have checked to make sure the environment variables exist in both python as well as the environment itself:

```
Last login: Fri Mar  8 17:26:58 2019 from xxxxxxxxxxxxx
[allitnil]$ echo $MAILUSER
(correct value)
[allitnil]$ echo $MAILPASS
(correct value)
[allitnil]$ python
Python 2.7.6 (default, Oct 26 2016, 20:30:19)
[GCC 4.8.4] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import os
>>> assert os.getenv('MAILUSER') == '(correct value)'
>>> assert os.getenv('MAILPASS') == '(correct value)'
>>> exit()
[allitnil]$
```

despite this, when i try to send an email from the contact form on the website, I get a 500 internal server error.

one thing I had trouble with was actually setting the env vars in .bashrc, while .bashrc would save properly and the export x=y would remain after I closed and re-sshd in, the variables would not show when trying to echo them or assert them in python. I was told to instead set the variables in .bash_profile, which remedied that issue.

.bash_profile

```
# ~/.bash_profile: executed by bash(1) for login shells.

umask 002
PS1='[\h]$ '

export MAILUSER="(correct value)"
export MAILPASS="(correct value)"
```

So, if the environment variables are correct, and the python application works when the literal strings are plugged in instead of os.environ.get('foo'), why do I keep returning 500 internal server error? I appreciate all of your help.

Answer (score 0):

**ANSWER**

Okay, so I noticed that when I would try to call the environment variables in flask, I would use

```
os.environ.get()
```

so I gave this a try:

```
os.getenv()
```

and it worked... what exactly is the difference though? I have seen both used almost interchangeably!